# Applying simple boundary conditions to a multi-variable function.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

If I have the following general differential equation solution (to Laplace equation):
$$
\phi(r,\theta)= A+B\ln(r)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(C_nr^n+\frac{D_n}{r^n}\right)\left( E_n \cos(n\theta) + F_n \sin(n\theta) \right) \quad \ \quad  (*)
$$
subject to $\phi(r=0,\theta=0)=0$, **why is the particular solution**
$$
\phi(r,\theta)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_nF_n r^n \sin(n\theta) \quad ?
$$
A priori, why $A=B=D_n=0 \ \forall \ n$ is clear. With these conditions $(*)$ becomes
$$
\phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_nr^n\left( E_n \cos(n\theta) + F_n \sin(n\theta) \right)
$$
However, I dont see why $E_n =0$, the above already satisfies the boundary conditions. Moreover couldn’t one keep $D_n\neq0$ provided $E_n=0$?

To me it seems as if there is not enough information to uniquely determine $\phi(r,\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. There is not enough information to get your particular solution from your general solution given the only boundary condition provided.

From your general solution, setting $\phi(r = 0, \theta) =0$, leads to $A = B = 0$ and $D_n = 0$. You are then left with
$$ \phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_nr^n\left( E_n \cos(n\theta) + F_n \sin(n\theta) \right),$$
or, with a redefinition of coefficients,
$$ \phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n\left( \alpha_n \cos(n\theta) + \beta_n \sin(n\theta) \right).$$
The values of $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ cannot be uniquely determined from the only condition you provide $\phi(r=0, \theta) =0$. Instead, we would need some additional condition like $F(\theta) = \phi(r = R, \theta)$, which would allow us to compute $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ according to
$$\alpha_n = \frac{1}{\pi R^n}\int^{2\pi}_{0} F(\theta) \cos(n \theta), \quad \beta_n = \frac{1}{\pi R ^n}\int^{2\pi}_{0} F(\theta) \sin(n \theta).$$
Sometimes the integration domain is $[-\pi, \pi]$ in which case we could use symmetry to eliminate one of the integrals. In either case, I think you're missing a boundary condition.

Comment: But given $\phi(0,0)=0$ as the only boundary condition, why can you separately consider $\phi(r,0)=0$ and $\phi(0,\theta)=0$?

Comment: I don't think you can separately consider the two conditions. If you set $r=0$, then the $\theta$ dependence no longer matters. So $\phi(0,0) = 0$ is redundant, and is actually just $\phi(0, \theta) = 0$ with $\theta$ set to zero, but $\theta$ could have been set to anything. Thus that is only one condition. In order to determine $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$, what you need is *another* condition for $\phi$ evaluated at some $r\neq 0$.

Comment: But couldn't you have said the same about $r$? Namely, $\phi(r,0)=0$ with $r$ set to $0$ but $r$ could have been set to anything.

Comment: Actually no. It's not the fact that $\phi =0$ that is important; it is the way $r$ and $\theta$ affect coordinate points. Working in $x$ and $y$ variables, if we have a function $\varphi(x,y)$ where $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, then setting $r = 0$ always gives us $x = y = 0$, but setting $\theta = 0$, just gives us $x = y = r$. Thus when $r = 0$, the function $\varphi$ loses all dependence on its independent variables, but this is not the case when $\theta =0$; in this latter case it is still dependent on $r$.

Comment: Riiiight, so it is to do with the fact that **as long as** $r=0$ then $\theta$ can be arbitrary since it will always refer to the origin point. Would $r\neq 0$ then $\theta$ should be properly specified as different $\theta$'s would correspond to different boundary conditions.

Comment: Yes. If you want a boundary condition at $r\neq 0$, then you wouldn't necessarily choose a specific value of $\theta$, but you would need to "specify" $\theta$ in some way. Namely, you would set $F(\theta) = \phi(r = \text{some value}, \theta)$ where $F(\theta)$ is a specific function of $\theta$. If you think about it, this makes sense from the term "boundary condition". For cylindrical coordinates, the boundary would be some cylindrical surface (defined by $r = R$ and variable $\theta$) rather than just a point on that surface. The $r=0$ line of points is the internal boundary cylinder.